# gallery with auto resizing images

Tags: jquery, html, gallery, lightbox

i want to make a image gallery with auto resizing images. Is that even possible?
this is how i want it to work

1. the container of the gallery is an element with fixed height and width
2. the preview of the images could be square so it doesn't matter if the images are portrait or landscape
3. the previews should resize itself according to how much images are inside of the container
4. then if you click on the preview a lightbox or something like that should open with navigation, description to the picture and close button

is there anybody who could help me with this?

Comment: i tried to place inside the container other containers for the images! I i didn't know how to realise this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample solution : [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/iwaruv/4/), [Code](http://jsbin.com/iwaruv/4/edit/) (would work only single line, instead see update below).

I am using [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), but you could use some other plugin.

**jQuery**:

```
var imgCount = $('.container img').length;
ContainerWidth = $('.container').outerWidth();
$('.container img').each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'width' : Math.floor(ContainerWidth/imgCount),
    'height' : 'auto'
  });
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

I found [this plugin](https://github.com/kdocki/jquery-collage), which seems to provide what [you need](http://www.keltdockins.com/2/post/2012/08/jquery-collage-plugin.html#145113000411941550).

Comment: i understand what you mean! but i want that the pictures use the whole place in the container! for example the container is width: 400px an height 800px and i got 10 pictures then there is just one line with small pictures and the rest of the container is unused!

Comment: thanks! that looks great! i also found [this plugin](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/comment-page-3/)